# Creating public action does not add to sequence

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I am a new user following this [tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-api-webapp) provided by IBM.

I am up to this step:

> For Cloudant Instance, select Input your own credentials and fill in the following fields with the credentials information captured for your cloudant service: Username, Password, Host and Database = guestbook and click Add and then Save.

After following the instruction to 'Add', I am returned to the sequence view (with the list of actions representing the sequence I'm working on).

**Expected**: The newly created public action w/ binding should appear in the list.

**Instead**: The newly created public action is not in the list. There is no evidence of it having been created at all. There is no option to 'save'.

*Am I doing something wrong? This seems like an enormous bug.*

---

Attempted solutions (unsuccessful):

- Log out and back in.
- Create new Cloudant service credentials.
- Enter service credentials manually vs via dropdown.
- Create action in a named package rather than default package.
- Create new Cloudant service credentials, selecting a specific service ID.

PS

- Attempted to create support ticket but needed to upgrade account by adding credit card. Filled in card information. Card rejected: "Error: Could not place order. Unable to verify the credit card. Declined due to Risk management". I use this card successfully all the time.
- In actions UI, selected a sequence, added an action to the sequence, 'reset' sequence to discard changes, began to add yet another action, cancelled that new action, returned to sequence view and the previously created action that I had discarded was there. Ie seems like some backend / database propagation issues on IBM's end?

Comment: What type of account do you have and in what region are you accessing IBM Cloud? Have you worked with Cloud Functions before?

Comment: data_henrik thanks, I currently have a Lite account and I'm in Melbourne, Australia. I've not worked with Cloud Functions before, however I have followed this tutorial to the letter.

Comment: @BenHogan I could reproduce the binding issue and raised the issue to the development team. I'll keep you posted here

Answer (score 0):

The steps have been updated in https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-api-webapp#sequence-of-actions-to-save-the-guestbook-entry.

To create the new Cloudant binding:

1. Set **Name** to **binding-for-guestbook**.
2. Set **Instance** to **Input your own credentials**.
3. Set **Username, Password, Host and IAM API Key** from the values found in the Cloudant credentials *for-guestbook* created earlier.
4. Set **Database** to **guestbook**.
5. Set **whiskoverwriteLabel** to **true**.
6. Save